# FIREBASE WARNING: Missing appcheck token (https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/)

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

I was using my own firebase account while development of application and later I used client's firebase config/project and now my app is showing this warning in browser console.
I am not able to read and write the firebase database.

How can I disable it, I checked in firebase account of client but APPCheck is not configured for that project, still warning is there in browse console.

`FIREBASE WARNING: Missing appcheck token (https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/)`

Please help, Thank You

Comment: Are you sure this warning is the cause of the problem? It's hard for us to say anything specific without seeing a minimal reproduction, but there are typically a lot more moving parts when changing to a different project.

Comment: Yes, I have added console logs, that does not print after this warning, what do you need to reproduce it?
I have tried a few ways like I have made the security rules public and then tried, but still same error. Also when I check users details, user gets logged in and I get uid, and loggedin time also updated. But it does not allow to create the collection in database or not allow to insert data. Even it does not provide update on info/connected database, I have used this to get online/offline update of user, but it does not trigger this also.
Can you tell suspected area to check ?

Comment: Hmmm... if the project doesn't enforce App Check, the warning might just be a red herring. You might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) with your project ID for personalized help in troubleshooting, so that they can double check that it's not being enforced.

Comment: I contacted to firebase support and they replied below:

"You are seeing this error because the Enforcement for Realtime Database is enabled. In this situation the database will allow only operations with valid AppCheck token"

and it solved my issue.

Comment: So App Check was configured to be enforced on the project after all? Good to hear ;